# How should I add a virtual currency using money-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, currency

How should we configure the new virtual currency "Fantasy Coins"

We do not want .00 like the usd

1 coin is the smallest unit and there should be no .00

So would subunit be 1?

Also thousands separator

Are there any advise on the conversion rate between "coins" and other currency's

We would like the output to be **Θ1,000**

```
config.register_currency = {
    :priority            => 100,
    :iso_code            => "COIN",
    :name                => "Fantasy Coins",
    :symbol              => "Θ",
    :symbol_first        => true,
    :subunit             => "Subcent",
    :subunit_to_unit     => 1,
    :thousands_separator => ",",
    :decimal_mark        => "."
  }
```